# Connect minikube pods to docker-machine network via proxy

Tags: proxy, docker-machine, http-proxy, squid, minikube

I would like my pods in my minikube-vm to use the network that my docker-machine uses. Inside the docker-machine I set up a proxy container(datadog/squid) for minikube to access, but I'm not sure exactly how to allow my minikube/pods to use this proxy. Should I be setting the env vars HTTP_PROXY or is there something else I need to do? Not sure what I should be looking into, any help would be appreciated, thanks!